# Delete duplicate row based on condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

I want to delete duplicate rows from a table based on a condition.

e.g.,
Table ABC:

```
ID  Name    Pin Status
111 Pope    909 New
222 Jazz    909 New
333 Volk    767 Assigned
444 Audi    767 New
555 Pink    435 New
```

I want to remove duplicate records which has same 'Pin' based on below conditions:

1. If both same Pin records have a Status of New – Delete any one of them.
2. If one of the same Pin records have a Status of New and the other have a Status of Assigned - Delete the 'New' status record.

I wrote the below SQL but I want to know if there is a better way to handle this using PK.

For 1:

```
DELETE FROM ABC WHERE ID IN (
SELECT
  a.id
FROM ABC a
WHERE a.rowid <
  (SELECT max(rowid)
  FROM  ABC  b
  WHERE b.pin = a.pin
  AND a.status  = b.status
  AND b.status  in ('New')
  )
);
```

For 2:

```
DELETE FROM ABC WHERE ID IN (
SELECT
  a.id
FROM ABC a
WHERE a.rowid <
  (SELECT max(rowid)
  FROM  ABC  b
  WHERE b.pin = a.pin
  AND a.status  <> b.status
  AND a.status  in ('New')
  AND b.status  in ('Assigned')
  )
);
```

Comment: what if a pin has multiple assigned and multiple new rows?

Comment: if both rows have same pin with Assigned status on both - do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
--Query 1:
DELETE FROM ABC
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID)
                 FROM ABC 
                 GROUP BY Pin
                 HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'New' THEN 1 END)
                );

--Query 2:
DELETE FROM ABC
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM ABC A
             WHERE status = 'New'
             AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC B 
                         WHERE A.Pin=B.Pin AND B.status='Assigned')

            );
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are at most two records for each `pin`:

```
DELETE FROM ABC
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN a.status = 'NEW' then rowid END) 
                FROM ABC a
                WHERE abc.pin = a.pin AND
                      a.status IN ('New', 'Assigned'
                GROUP BY a.pin
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query--

```
-- Select ID, Name, Pin, Status
Delete
From (
    Select  
        ID, Name, Pin, Status,
        Row_Number() Over(Partition By Pin Order By Pin) As PinRowNum,
        Row_Number() Over(Partition By Pin, Status Order By Status) As 
    StatusRowNum
From ABC
) As D Where StatusRowNum > 1 Or (PinRowNum > 1 And StatusRowNum = 1)
```